# Programmatically Create Controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the best way to dynamically create a controller in Rails.

I've got a class that needs to generate a bunch of controller that inherit from it.  I could just create a bunch of files in /app/controllers, but they'd all be basically empty files.  There's got to be a way to generate these classes dynamically and have them treated like other controllers in Rails, e.g. reloaded correctly in dev mode.

I tried putting this in a config/initializer:

```
FL.contact_types.each do |contact_type|
  controller_name = "#{contact_type.pluralize}Controller"
  Object.const_set(controller_name.to_sym, Class.new(ContactsController)) unless Object.const_defined?(controller_name.to_sym)
end
```

This worked, but I run into the dependency/reload problem and get “A copy of AuthenticatedSystem has been removed from the module tree but is still active” since the ContactsController inherits from ApplicationController which includes AuthenticatedSystem.

Is creating a bunch of empty files really the best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you need multiple controllers?  Can you have a single controller that gets passed a value to indicate how it behaves?  You could also make a module that has the common functionality in it, and have the empty controller files that only reference the module.

a route could be used to pass the type in:

```
map.route "/:type_of_contact/:action/:id/, {:controller => :contact_type}
```

now in all the actions, in params you have the key :type_of_contact to guide your system.

You'll want to make sure this is near the end of your routes so it doesn't override access to your other controllers.

Comment: It sounds like you want a catch-all controller for a specific set of incoming actions.

Comment: Well, I thought I wanted a separate controller for each ContactType.  They are all contacts, but a few have an extra field or two, so STI seemed like the right way to go. And it works, but I just was trying to get around all of the controllers that did exactly the same thing, so I then had them all inherit from ContactsController.

I could get rid of the extra controllers, though, and do everything through the ContactsController.  I'd just need to set the type explicitly and I couldn't use the form_for magic.  I guess that might still be the way to go, though.  Just different mess.

Comment: Well, I went with the solution of just running everything through my contacts controller.  I don't love it, but it seems like there's tradeoffs both ways.  This way seemed like I had to use fewer hacks.  I guess that says something. :)  Thank

Comment: Theres no reason you can't use the form_for.  If you pass the instance variable at the to it: <%= form_for(@any_contact) %> then you don't need to care about the specific type.  If you absolutely do care about the specific type, then you can set a variable to a symbol based on your type column.